# Installing configuration from a module that is tracked in configuration on deployment

Tags: 9, configuration

I am trying to install a module on a higher level environment. The module installs configuration in its config/install directory, and that configuration was also exported to the main site configuration folder. On the upper environment, I cannot install the module now (configuration already exists). How do you support this case? Do you deploy the install first (core.extention.yml), then come in behind it with the additional config it exports to the normal Drupal configuration directory?

Comment: Did the module activation ship originally in core.extension?

Comment: Nope - I just noticed that. I may have been bit by config_split again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the module’s exported config first then re-add it along with the module activation.

Technically all you have to do is remove the module’s configuration from active configuration, which you can do with Drush.

Comment: Yep, got bit by config_split. Didn't notice it did not export the module enable to core.extension.yml. This would also work.